# InitTelInput — how to set correct padding left in input?

Tags: javascript, css

I use [InitTelInput](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) in my project.

If i init this lib all work good.

[image]

```
<input type="tel" class="form__tel-input" id="phone" placeholder="">

.form__tel-input {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24.5px 24px 25.5px 126px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 170%;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

$(() => {
    $('#phone').intlTelInput({
        hiddenInput: 'full_number',
        initialCountry: 'auto',
        geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
            $.get('https://api.sypexgeo.net/json/', function (location) {
                let countryCode = location.country.iso;
                callback(countryCode);
            })
        },
        separateDialCode: true,
    });
})
```

https://codepen.io/ivstepin/pen/JjJbRrd?editors=1111

But if i add padding for .iti__flag-container then country selector overlaps input.

[image]

```
.iti__flag-container {
  padding: 16px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ivstepin/pen/NWgbRLB?editors=1111

How to make correct padding for input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css to correctly style the input

```
.iti__flag-container {
    margin: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

.iti {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
}

.form__tel-input {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24.5px 24px 25.5px 166px;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 170%;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    outline: none;
}
```

You can checkout this in action [here](https://codepen.io/vijaykumawat/pen/MWobGyB?editors=1111) in codepane

Comment: It's not working. You can see — https://codepen.io/ivstepin/pen/YzQpVwE?editors=1111

Each time when new country code selected this lib calculate new padding left for input. I can set static padding-left, but it's bad idea.

Comment: Ohh I missed the position property to mention. I have updated the answer now. this should work. add position relative to iti__flag-container. Also we have set the container to flex so the static padding left will not cause any issue.